# Unable to locate text input element using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find an element on a webpage (https://www.fimea.fi/web/en/databases_and_registeries/spcs/human_medicinal_products) using Selenium and Python and I want to find the first text input for name of the medicinal product.

I am getting this error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='nimi'][@type='text']"}
```

I am currently using the code below:

```
clear_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='nimi'][@type='text']")
```

I am new to Python and Selenium. Please help me out on this.

Comment: Please add the html of the element you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field you are looking for is inside an `iframe`.
You need to identify and switch to that `iframe` first.

```
iframe=driver.switch_to.frame('_com_liferay_iframe_web_portlet_IFramePortlet_INSTANCE_1UG85fOFT8Za_iframe')
input_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='nimi']")
```

Comment: Thanks, I am able to locate it now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't locate the element is that the input box is hiden by a frame. Maybe you should use `switch_to.frame()` to switch to it.
[F12 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37yS9.png)